# How can I know if I'm suspended or banned from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?  (the answer is here, in this post)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

I was very desperate and was in front of the computer for too long when I asked a stupid question that a simple google search would solve. Now I'm not able to ask questions in Stack Overflow anymore and this has continued for some weeks now.

Immediately after an offense my account was flagged with 1 and I was not able to submit new questions.

From the "Why am I getting this message?" answer in: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

"No, a suspension is a manual, temporary penalty during which a user cannot ask questions, nor post answers."

So, my account is not flagged with 1 rep. anymore but I still can't post new questions. This means I'm banned?

Comment: For one, you were serially downvoted on June 25. That's definitely not helping...

Comment: @Tart Levee I read it but and I see "If you are banned from asking questions but you tripped the heuristic by just a tiny bit, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure. And even if you're lucky then you're still very close to being banned again, if you get new downvotes."

But I thought this information could be somewhere explicit on the site. The only way to know is by trying to ask a question and getting the warning?

Comment: I'm sure [this didn't help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639026/syntax-error-with-mysql-workbench-and-if-statement/). I've flagged your first answer as a non-answer.

Comment: I really don't know why this is being considered as dup since I asked how do I know if I'm suspended or banned and not why I'm receiving the warning message. I saw from the thread that one is permanent and the other is temporary with an account flagged with 1 reputation.

Comment: Are you getting the message *“Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?*  If you are, the linked duplicate has all the information you need.

Comment: To be exact, I'm receiving: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."

Comment: @HugoFS and it didn't occur to you to click the link to learn more?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, I followed the link, but from that post it is not clear for me if I'm banned or suspended.